# How to fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of Javascript code that worked before on PHP5.6 
However, when I upgraded to PHP7.2 it stopped working and getting this error below:

```
VM505:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.tools.min.js:49)
    at Function.httpData (jquery.tools.min.js:152)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (jquery.tools.min.js:149)
globalEval  @   jquery.tools.min.js:49
httpData    @   jquery.tools.min.js:152
x.onreadystatechange    @   jquery.tools.min.js:149
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
ajax    @   jquery.tools.min.js:150
chkpwd  @   hw.php:295
onclick @   hw.php:877
```

I can't figure out that the error said chkpwd @ hw.php 295, but this function is actually in LINE 387. So, I don't know where to look into.

What's the best way to debug this and fix it?

```
function chkpwd() {

  var pwd_val = $("#engpassword").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'password.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'processData',
    data: {
      pwd: pwd_val,
      callback: 'pwdaction'
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      alert('Ajax request error!');
      $(e.target).attr('disabled', false);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Your PHP script (or the web server) is sending out HTML instead of JSON. Usually this is because the script is trying to report an error. Try loading the script directly (instead of via ajax), or load it as a non-jsonp AJAX request, so you can see the raw output.

Comment: @Daniel Beck,  From where to look into the raw output?

Comment: If there's a syntax error in the script you'll be able to see the error message by just loading the script directly in the browser.  If that doesn't trigger the error, change your ajax request to something other than jsonp and console.log the response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually it refers to a response that instead of being a parsable JSON returns (IE) an HTML which opening tag begins with `<`

Comment: Just open your network browser inspector and check the response from the server: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*O1xWZKun2J2hHe6LmoNyBA.gif

Comment: Thanks! I really found an angle bracket '>' at the returned value. After I remove that, everything worked again!

Comment: In my case, the path I specified for the worker was not the right path

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with React app and you see this error in your console, it might be due to the missing "type" attribute of the script tag in your index.html file. Make sure to include type="text/jsx".

Also, the URL that you are trying to access is not returning Javascript or JSON but HTML, give the correct path to the "src" attribute of your script tag beginning with "/" followed by the path of the .js file.

I took reference from the following link, do take a look as I have just briefed what was written in this article: https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token#n

PS - Go through the comments section within the article

Answer (score 1):

Just add `type="text/jsx"
into your index.html in public file.

```
<script src="./src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case ( Webpack v.5 + React ) it was happen on pages with 2nd or more nested level of pages. All assets are included using relative path like `sct="./index.js"`. So for nested pages become broken.

To fix it need to add `<base href="http://yoursitename.com">`

If you are using webpack you can add:

```
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
  title: WebSiteName,
  base: isLocal ? 'http://localhost:4008' : 'http://yoursitename.com',
});
```

which will inject the element `<base href="...">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SPA like React. This can also be caused by the failure launch of your SPA application. In my case, the port 9999 has already been allocated.

Just find the process and kill it. Then everything works fine.
`lsof -i TCP:9999`

Answer (score 0):

I removed `homepage` from `package.json` file and the error gone

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error when I access an index.html or index.php page and forget to put a trailing slash at the end of the url.

`http://example.com/app` (doesn't work)

vs

`http://example.com/app/` (works)